# Avoid duplicates in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, tuples

The students are doing projects in pairs.

Rules: No one is allowed to work alone; every project is done by exactly two students. No two students may work together on more than one project.

Each project is composed by the names of the two students who did the project and the mark (an integer from 0 to 100).

I'm writing a function called `legalCourse` which takes a `CourseData` as a parameter and returns a `Bool`. Returns
`True` if the course data is “legal”, meaning that it contains neither of the kinds of errors listed above.  For all of the remaining functions.
sample output:

```
*legalCourse [("John","Mary",75)]
True
* legalCourse [("John","John",75)]
False
* legalCourse [("John","Mary",75),("Peter","Paul",90),("John","Mary",90)]
False
* legalCourse [("John","Mary",75),("Peter","Paul",90),("Mary","John",90)]
False
*Assignment2> legalCourse [("John","Mary",75),("Peter","Paul",90),("Mary","Fred",90)]
True
```

code:

```
type CourseData = [(String, String, Int)]
legalCourse :: CourseData -> Bool
legalCourse course = legal1 course && legal2 course
where
    -- legal1 course means the course does not contain any projects like ("David","David",90)
    legal1 [] = True
    legal1 ((name1,name2,_):moreGroups) = name1 /= name2 && legal1 moreGroups
    -- hasPair course name1 name2 means the course has a project done by name1 and name2
    -- (in either order)
    hasPair [] _ _ = False
    hasPair ((a,b,_):moreGroups) name1 name2 =
        (a == name1 && b == name2) || (a == name2 && b == name1) || hasPair moreGroups name1 name2
    -- legal2 course means the course does not contain two projects done by the same
    -- pair of students (regardless of order)
    legal2 [] = True
    legal2 [_] = True
    legal2 ((name1,name2,_):moreProjects) = 
        not (hasPair moreProjects name1 name2) && legal2 moreProjects
```

I don't understand `hasPair` and `legal2`, how does this part

```
hasPair ((a,b,_):moreGroups) name1 name2 =
    (a == name1 && b == name2) || (a == name2 && b == name1) || hasPair moreGroups name1 name2
```

avoid same pairs of people doing project?

Comment: Is this your code, or something provided in your course materials?

Comment: It's solution provided in the class which I don't understand.

Comment: The problem looks more for Prolog, than for Haskell :)

Comment: This implementation looks fairly suspect in terms of Haskell design principles. I'll write up a better implementation of `CourseData` that makes illegal sets of projects unrepresentable soon.

Answer (score 2):

`hasPair` searches its first argument for a pair that matches its next two arguments.

An empty list of pairs doesn't have a pair that matches the other arguments, regardless of what they are.

```
hasPair [] _ _ = False
```

A list with a student pair `(a, b, _)` and some more pairs `moreGroups` will match the pair of students `name1` and `name2` if ...

```
hasPair ((a,b,_):moreGroups) name1 name2 =
```

Students `a` and `b` are `name1` and `name2`. This could happen in either order.

```
    (a == name1 && b == name2) || (a == name2 && b == name1) || ...
```

Or if one of the remaining groups is `name1` and `name2`.

```
    ... hasPair moreGroups name1 name2
```

`hasPair` doesn't make sure there's no group doing *any two projects*, but when considering a single project it can be used to make sure there's no *other project* being done by the same group.

Answer (score 1):

`hasPair xs name1 name2` checks whether there is a 3-tuple in the list `xs` where the first two elements are `name1` and `name2`, though not in that order. `legal2` applies this same check for every project group, but in such a way that each pair of projects only gets checked once. I think the 'hasPair' function would be more understandable with a type signature. Here's (I think), a clearer definition of the function:

```
hasPair :: Eq a => [(a, a, b)] -> a -> a -> Bool
hasPair []               _  _  = False
hasPair ((x1, x2, _):xs) y1 y2
  | x1 == y1 && x2 == y2 = True
  | x1 == y2 && x2 == y1 = True
  | otherwise            = hasPair xs y1 y2
```

Comment: `hasPair` needs an `Eq a` constraint added to the type signature to use `x1 == y1` etc.

Comment: @Cirdec Yes it did. Fixed. I should check that the snippet works before posting.

Comment: how about `(x1,x2)==(y1,y2)` instead of `x1 == y1 && x2 == y2 `

Comment: @karakfa Yes, that would be more succinct and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Data.Set (Set,fromList)

data CourseData = CourseData String String Int deriving Show
```

Make `Eq` and `Ord` instances that ignore the grade and expect the student names to be sorted already.

```
instance Eq CourseData where
  (==) (CourseData a b _) (CourseData a' b' _) = a == a' && b == b'

instance Ord CourseData where
  compare (CourseData a b _) (CourseData a' b' _) = compare a a' `mappend` compare b b'
```

Make it impossible to make an "incorrect" `CourseData` by sorting the names.

```
mkCourseData :: String -> String -> Int -> CourseData
mkCourseData a b = case compare a b of
  -- Make sure the greater element is to the right
  GT -> CourseData b a
  _ -> CourseData a b
```

As you can see, this makes `Set`s of `CourseData` follow your rules:

```
test :: Set CourseData
test = fromList [mkCourseData "a" "b" 1,mkCourseData "b" "a" 2]
```

This comes out to `fromList [CourseData "a" "b" 2]`

Answer (score 0):

another compositional alternative

```
import Data.List(sort,group)

legalCourse = null . filter (>1) . map length . group . sort . map dictOrder
         where dictOder (x,y,_) = if (x<y) then (x,y) else (y,x)
```